# react-native run-android giving error: Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0

Tags: android, react-native

I have been trying to start my react app and facing below error,
I have tried the steps mentioned in stackoverflow,

1. for clearing .graddle in root of the project
2. clearing C:\Users<user>.gradle\caches

But these have not work. Running is completely in cli now not in any ide.
Any help would be gratly appreciated.

```
npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 896 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
.............10%..............20%..............30%..............40%..............50%
..............60%..............70%..............80%..............90%..............100%
Deleting directory C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

at makeError (E:\pt\uipoc\PW\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at E:\pt\uipoc\PW\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (E:\pt\uipoc\PW\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (E:\pt\uipoc\PW\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "PW",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.14.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RCA
possibly because I ran "react-native run-android" before starting android virtual machine via (ADM manager provided by android studio)
followed steps from https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Solution:
Delete C:\Users<user>.gradle\daemon